# How to use Windows Enviroment Variable in Python Web Script as shebang

Tags: python

I am creating a Python script for Web with version 3.7 portable in Windows 10, I use a shebang on the first line that specifies the path of the Python exe and the script runs correctly.

Example:

```
#!C:/python/python.exe -u
```

I have an environment variable called% PY_WIN% with the location of the python folder, when I use it in cmd, python works fine.

I want to use the environment variable on the first line of all my scripts instead of the absolute location. How do i do it?

example:

```
#!%PY_WIN%/python.exe -u
```

Note: The last example of shebang, dont run, this script return "500 internal Server Error" in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a virtual environment on windows but maybe try something like:

```
#!C:/%PY_WIN%/python.exe -u
```

or maybe:

```
#!C:/python/%PY_WIN%/python.exe -u
```

No guarantee but just an idea. Hope you find something that works!

Comment: %PY_WIN% enviroment variable, contains full path of python executable.